# OPTION (HASH GROUP) Not Accepted In Derived Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can use OPTION (HASH GROUP) in the first but not the second.  How can I include OPTION (HASH GROUP) in the second?

```
  SELECT 
  count(*) as 'match'  
  FROM [docSVenum1] with (nolock)   
  INNER LOOP JOIN  [FTSindexWordOnce] as w1 with (NOLOCK, FORCESEEK) 
    ON [docSVenum1].sID = w1.[sID] and [docSVenum1].[enumID] = '142'
  INNER HASH JOIN [FTSindexWordOnce] as w2 with (NOLOCK)
    ON  w1.wordID = w2.wordID and w2.[sID] = '2'      
  GROUP BY W1.[sID]
  OPTION (HASH GROUP)


select max(list.match) as 'max'
  from
  (
      SELECT 
       count(*) as 'match'  
      FROM [docSVenum1] with (nolock)   
      INNER LOOP JOIN  [FTSindexWordOnce] as w1 with (NOLOCK, FORCESEEK) 
        ON [docSVenum1].sID = w1.[sID] and [docSVenum1].[enumID] = '142'
      INNER HASH JOIN [FTSindexWordOnce] as w2 with (NOLOCK)
        ON  w1.wordID = w2.wordID and w2.[sID] = '2'      
      GROUP BY W1.[sID]
      -- OPTION (HASH GROUP)
  ) as list;
```

in real life the full query will be more like this

```
    select max(list.match) as 'max'
  from
  (
      SELECT 200*count(*)/([d1].[textSize] + [d2].[textSize]) as 'match'  
      FROM [docSVenum1] with (nolock)   
      INNER LOOP JOIN  [FTSindexWordOnce] as w1 with (NOLOCK, FORCESEEK) 
        ON [docSVenum1].sID = w1.[sID] and [docSVenum1].[enumID] = '142'
      INNER HASH JOIN [FTSindexWordOnce] as w2 with (NOLOCK)
        ON  w1.wordID = w2.wordID and w2.[sID] = '2'
      JOIN docSVsys as d1 with (nolock)
        on d1.sID = w1.sID
      JOIN docSVsys as d2 with (nolock)
        on d2.sID = w1.sID    
      GROUP BY W1.[sID],  [d1].[textSize], [d2].[textSize]
      -- OPTION (HASH GROUP) 
  ) as list;
```

Comment: What is your build of SQL Server 2008? [I found this bug during the SQL Server 2012 beta](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/615767/denali-engine-regression-in-query-hint-behavior) but the issue may have existed in early builds of 2008/2008 R2 as well. Also does the hint apply correctly if you add the option after `as list`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) 
 Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: @AaronBertrand And if I try and put it after the list I also get a syntax error.

Comment: What error are you getting for the original version of the query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

Comment: And assuming this is a bug and may take months before we see a fix, what is the reason you must also add - on top of all these other hints - the hash group option? What is the overall impact of this change on the query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Right now it is manageable without.  What I do is run the inner with the HASH GROUP and it learns.  But I would rather have something explicit.  The FORCESEEK and HASH GROUP improve the query  12X (most of that is the FORCESEEK).

Comment: I think you're doing way too much thinking for the optimizer. I bet you can optimize this better by focusing on structure, indexes and stats rather than hard-coding all of these conditions. Just MHO.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to use the option outside of the subquery (after `as list`) on SQL Server 2005 (without the forceseek hint, version = 9.0.5266), 2008 (10.0.5785) and 2012 (11.0.2316). But on 2008 R2 (10.50.2811) the error message I get is:

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

```
SELECT MAX(x.match) FROM (
SELECT 
  count(*) as match  
  FROM sys.objects AS o with (nolock, forceseek)   
  INNER LOOP JOIN sys.columns as c with (NOLOCK) 
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
  INNER HASH JOIN sys.columns as c2 with (NOLOCK)
    ON o.object_id = c2.object_id   
  GROUP BY o.object_id
) AS x
  OPTION (HASH GROUP);
```

If I don't use an aggregate, it works:

```
SELECT x.match FROM (
SELECT 
  count(*) as match  
  FROM sys.objects AS o with (nolock, forceseek)   
  INNER LOOP JOIN sys.columns as c with (NOLOCK) 
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
  INNER HASH JOIN sys.columns as c2 with (NOLOCK)
    ON o.object_id = c2.object_id   
  GROUP BY o.object_id
) AS x
  OPTION (HASH GROUP);
```

And if I use this variation which uses TOP instead of MAX, it also works:

```
SELECT TOP (1) x.match FROM (
SELECT 
  count(*) as match  
  FROM sys.objects AS o with (nolock, forceseek)   
  INNER LOOP JOIN sys.columns as c with (NOLOCK) 
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
  INNER HASH JOIN sys.columns as c2 with (NOLOCK)
    ON o.object_id = c2.object_id   
  GROUP BY o.object_id
) AS x
  ORDER BY x.match DESC
  OPTION (HASH GROUP);
```

And maybe even try eliminating the subquery (assuming that is only there to isolate the max - if so it isn't necessary):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
  count(*) as [max]  
  FROM sys.objects AS o with (nolock, forceseek)   
  INNER LOOP JOIN sys.columns as c with (NOLOCK) 
    ON o.object_id = c.object_id
  INNER HASH JOIN sys.columns as c2 with (NOLOCK)
    ON o.object_id = c2.object_id   
  GROUP BY o.object_id
  ORDER BY [max] DESC
  OPTION (HASH GROUP);
```

I have a question in to see if this is a similar issue that I had reported against SQL Server 2012. I'll update here when I know more.

Comment: Thanks  In real life that count(*) as match is count(*) / something-dynamic so cannot just do a single count(*)

Comment: @Blam if you want help with your real query, you'll need to show your real query. Or reproduce the exact problem with catalog views (as I have done).